# Private file upload using core's contact module

Tags: forms, files

I am using the core contact form module for user applications. I have set a private file upload directory in `settings.php`. When the user submits the application form I require them to also upload a CV (`.pdf` and `.docx` file types).

The file upload doesn't work and there are no errors in watchdog. Should I use webform, and if I use will I not loose the entries I already have, without the file attached?

Comment: What you should do is a totally opinion-based thing. I'd suggest you simply try it out yourself in a local development environment. Then you'll know.

Comment: so the core drupal contact module doesn't allow this function?

Comment: If you can add an upload field to the contact form I guess this should work. But "upload doesn't work" is too broad.

Comment: The form submits, but when i check in contact storage as admin, I can view all the other form input fields except the file upload path or url.

Comment: Maybe because it's private?

Comment: I didn't think the core contact form allowed storage at all by default in core. Only with a module like contact_storage does that work. The Message entity has a Null storage entity, which overrides all the methods to not do anything.